# Visual Studio 2022 "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: obj"

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web

I am getting an error when opening C# .NET 4.x project as a website in Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.4.3.
[image: Error message]

"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: obj"

I was able to open it as a website without the error before the latest update for Visual Studio.

When I click OK, it takes me back to the list of websites from IIS. Even though I get the error, the code still loads, and I can edit it if I close the error.

There are a few other stack overflow questions with similar topics, but none for this version of visual studio that relate to opening a project as a website.

Comment: If you can't find a solution, in the end you can [report the problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report) to the Dev team

Comment: I reported the problem to Microsoft 

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar error "Value cannot be null parameter name: value" while adding the project refrence or Assembly refrence. Was using VS 2022 and target framework ".Net Framework 4.8". Finally resolve the issue by removing the broken refrences. Once removed clean and rebuilt the solution and was able to add the references.
[image]

[image]

[image]